# Ubuntu/Qt Application

Tags: application-development

In Qt Creator:

1. Is the 'Qt GUI Application' completely different from 'Ubuntu touch GUI Application'?
2. Does Ubuntu App Developer community accept 'Qt GUI Application' developed on Ubuntu platform?

Comment: 1 . No, ubuntu touch ui is a subset of Qt toolkit

2. Did'nt got what you mean by it . A pure qt app is well supported in ubuntu desktop

Answer (score 1):

The **Ubuntu Touch Simple UI** aplication template helps you create the basics of an application that uses the Ubuntu SDK and has the native look and feel of Ubuntu and can integrate with the rest of the platform. It is the recommended way to start writing your first apps in Ubuntu, and you'll be using the QML programming language.

The **Qt GUI application**, will create a basic app using Qt only, but it will not use the Ubuntu SDK (unless you manually add it later). The app will be based on the Qt foundations and C++. It's not the recommended way to get started, but the app you create will run fine in Ubuntu, although it might not have the native look and feel of other Ubuntu apps.

And yes, while we recommend and encourage using the Ubuntu SDK, our community will welcome almost any kind of app and contributions you make to Ubuntu! :)